Border bleed on a button with slide animation
Problem
I am trying to create a button with a sliding animation. The button has a border-radius and uses pseudo-elements to achieve the effect.
Here is the markup:
<div role="button" class="is-style-rt-primary-accent-button">
  <a class="rt-button__link" data-text="HELLO WORLD" href="#" target="_self" rel="noopener">
    HELLO WORLD
    <div class="rt-button">
      <div class="rt-button__circle">
        <div class="rt-button__arrow">
          <span class="rt-button__line"></span>
            <span class="rt-button__pointer"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>

Here are the styles:
.is-style-rt-primary-accent-button {
    .rt-button__link {
        display: inline-flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        background: none;
        font-weight: 700;
        padding: 14px 31px;
        position: relative;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 28px;
        overflow: hidden;
        transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        border-radius: 64px;
        z-index: 1;
        color: var(--wp--preset--color--accent-1);
        text-decoration: none;

        &::after {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            border-radius: 64px;
            background: var(--wp--preset--color--accent-6);
            transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
            z-index: -2;
        }

        &::before {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            left: -100%;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            border-radius: 64px;
            background: var(--wp--preset--color--secondary);
            transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
            z-index: -1;
        }

        &:hover {
            color: var(--wp--preset--color--accent-6);

            .rt-button__line {
                background: var(--wp--preset--color--accent-6);
            }

            .rt-button__pointer {
                border-left: 0.3125rem solid var(--wp--preset--color--accent-6);
            }

            .rt-button__arrow {
                transform: translateX(10px);
            }

            &::before {
                transform: translateX(100%);
            }
        }
    }

    .rt-button__circle {
        @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
            background: none;
        }
    }

    .rt-button__arrow {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        margin-left: 1rem;
        transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
    }

    .rt-button__line {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 0.625rem;
        height: 0.125rem;
        vertical-align: middle;
        background: var(--wp--preset--color--accent-1);
    }

    .rt-button__pointer {
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-top: 0.3125rem solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 0.3125rem solid transparent;
        border-left: 0.3125rem solid var(--wp--preset--color--accent-1);
    }
}

Here is the recording of the issue with animations slowed down to 25%. Notice that at the X borders, there is a bleed.

What I have tried

I have tried playing with z-index and borders. The bleed still persists.
Using a div instead of pseudoelements to handle the background animations.
Using box-shadow but since the animation is different, I did not pursue that option further.
Scaling the foreground (black layer) upon hover.


This is a common bug with CSS whenever stacking two elements with a background-color and the same border-radius on top of each other, and unfortunately I haven't seen any definitive way to solve this problem, especially with transforms involved (although there are a few hacks that I've seen that approach the solution). There are many different iterations of this same problem on Stack Overflow. I have hope that background-clip will eventually be able to solve this issue (or maybe we could get browsers to just work out of the box), but caniuse.com specifically lists bugs with background-clip concerning stacking behaviors.
Here is a Stack Overflow question that helps illustrate the actual problem of what is causing the strange clipping near the borders. But unfortunately when dealing with moving elements like this defined with position relative and absolute, finding a more robust solution is difficult.
Luckily your use case makes things considerably easier, because the background color is the same as the button color, so you don't need to use overflow hidden on the same element that has the border radius. A little sleight of hand makes our not pixel-perfect monstrosity look elegant.
Here's a miminal reproducible version of your code with my solution implemented:


body {
    background-color:rgb(22, 22, 22);
    padding: 100px;
}

.btn {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: white;
    color: rgb(234, 60, 161);
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 999px;
    background-clip: content-box;
}

.btn:hover {
    color: white;
}

.cover-element {
    position: absolute;
    background-color:rgb(22, 22, 22);
    width: 206px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 999px;
    top: 0;
    left: -240px;
    transition: all .5s;
    background-clip: content-box;
}

.btn:hover > .cover-element {
    left: -3px;
}
<div style="width: 202px; height: 50px; overflow: hidden;">
    <a href="#" class="btn">
        <div style="z-index: 2;">HELLO WORLD</div>
        <div class="cover-element "></div>
    </a>
</div>



It works by making the pseudo element 3px wider on each side, with an outer div using overflow: hidden. If you change the background-color of the body you'll see the magic disappear, and realize that this only works with your particular use-case.
I haven't included the extra arrow element in the solution, but you should be able to implement it as is.

Although this solution would work for this problem, the solution is not generalizable. The increase in width, although possible in this scenario, would be easily distinguishable when the background is not the same as the slide color.
Thank you for your solution though.

Yes unfortunately that is true. That's why I say in my answer it only works in your particular use case. I hope they fix this bug eventually.

The key to eliminating the bleed was the use of pseudo-elements and carefully timed transitions. Here's what I have done:
I used ::after for the background and ::before for the sliding overlay.
The background was given a transition for opacity:
&::after {
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

On hover, I set the opacity of the background to 0 with a slight delay:
&:hover {
  &::after {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.2s ease-out 0.1s;
  }
}

The sliding overlay (::before) was given a transform transition:
&::before {
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
}

On hover, I slide in the overlay:
&:hover {
  &::before {
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
  }
}

Although there is a minor flicker, it is negligible.
This is how it looks:

